# App sleeps despite setIdleTimerDisabled being set

Tags: ios

I'm writing a Swift application and want the app to not fall asleep if it's on a certain view controller.

I am using this bit of code to signal that the app should not be put to sleep:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

And once they leave the view I flip it back to false to save on battery life. However, it seems like the app will still be put to sleep eventually?

When I run the app on my iPad 2, eventually the screen dims and it falls asleep. On my iPhone 6 I haven't been able to reproduce the problem.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something very basic here?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this in AppDelegate and use the passed value "application".

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        application.idleTimerDisabled = true   
        return true
    }
```